# Kibana custom control for boolean filters

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana 7.1, and want to have a control to turn on filters, e.g. I would like a switch like control that would turn a filter on/off and allow us to see data through that context? Does this exist somewhere? Is there a good tutorial on how to make a custom control?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify where you want to use this kind of "switch"? In the discovery or in visualizations?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill I would like to be able to use this on a custom dashboard to affect visualizations on the dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comments section, you want to use a control that affects filters on dashboards/visualizations. For this use case one would create a controls visualization. Therefore click on Visualize -> Create Visualization -> Controls.

You can decide between an options list and a range slider. I've created an options list on the agent.hostname field on filebeat indices.

[image]

Check out the options tab as well for fine tuning your needs.

Since this is a normal visualization, you can add it to your dashboard and apply filters via the options list and range sliders. If you checked 'Update Kibana filters on each change' on the options tab in the controls visualization, the filters will be applied to the data on the dashboard.

I hope I could help you!

Comment: I am familiar with the controls you are talking with, range sliders only work for numeric fields, and an options list seems a bit of an overkill for a list that could only be true/false, what I am looking for is something more along the lines of the binary switches in the configuration section of kibana, that would let me have a filter that I could toggle on/off, or a field that I could say filter to true/false.